# for in function that call it self (nested functioning)

Tags: c++, nested, nested-loops

i tell my opinion by sample ...
if we input the a sequence like {a,b,c,d} and if we choose the number of the elements of the each subsequences 3 it should be out output ...
a,b,c | a,b,d | a,c,d | b,c,d  .... note that the arrangement is important (i'm  using array) its some kind of output the whole subset which contain 3 element of a sequence ....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int p = 0, q = 0, i;
void allinone(int thing[], int n, int sub, int tek[], int sum[])
{
    for (i = p;i <= n - sub + p;i++)
    {
        tek[q] = thing[i];
        if (p < sub - 1)
        {
            ++q;
            ++p;
            allinone(thing, n, sub, tek, sum);
        }
        if (q == (sub - 1))
        {
            for (auto out_p = 0;out_p <= p;out_p++)
                std::cout << tek[out_p] << "\t";
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    --q; 
    return; // not need
}
int main()
{
    constexpr int n=5, sub=3; //delete the constexpr if ur compiler is mingw
    /*std::cout << "enter array len : "; //add this if ur compiler is mingw
    std::cin >> n; // number of elements in sequence
    std::cout << "enter sub that u want: ";
    std::cin >> sub;*/ // subset 
    int sum[sub], tek[sub], thing[n];
    for (i = 0;i <= n - 1;i++)
        std::cin >> thing[i];
    allinone(thing, n, sub, tek, sum);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

which part is making the program not turn back to the previous function ...

see the steps bellow ...

i think the problem made by my thought that of the promises

```
#allinone1
first for pormise me it will do this for the i=0,1    
{
doing for i=1{
sequence{a,b,c,d}   thing[0]=a,thing[1]=b,thing[2]=c,thing[3]=d
tek[0] = a ... go into if ... p=1 , q=1 ... and again its going into the #allinone2 ... 
now in the for its promise me to do this for i=1,2
{
doing for i=1
tek[1]= b ... go into if ... p=2 ,q=2 ... and again its going to #allinone3
another for its promise me to do this with i=2,3 
{
doing for i=2 
tek[2]= c .. go into the output if ... output a b c 
doing for i=3
tek[2]= d .. go into output if ... output a d d 
}get out of for 
q=1
end of the allinone3 
go into allinone 2 for 
q is not 2 ... 
doing for i=2 // i think this part made the problem ....
and ...
```

i think its not storing the last i's ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem that I see is that you are modifying the global variable `i` in `main` as well as `allinone`.

When you are dealing with recursive functions, its best to pass the values of variables that are used to terminate recursion as arguments to the function.

I updated your code a little bit to make the recursion go a little further. However, it is not perfect all the way. It produces output like:

```
2 3 3
```

I'll let you figure out the final bit.

```
#include <iostream>

// Don't use global variables for variables that are used
// to terminate recursion.
// int p = 0, q = 0, i;

void allinone(int thing[], int n, int p, int sub, int tek[], int sum[])
{
    int q = p;
    for (int i = p; i <= n - sub + p; i++)
    {
        tek[q] = thing[i];
        if (p < sub - 1)
        {
           allinone(thing, n, p+1, sub, tek, sum);
        }
        if (q == (sub - 1))
        {
            for (auto out_p = 0;out_p <= p;out_p++)
                std::cout << tek[out_p] << "\t";
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    constexpr int n=5, sub=3; //delete the constexpr if ur compiler is mingw
    /*std::cout << "enter array len : "; //add this if ur compiler is mingw
    std::cin >> n; // number of elements in sequence
    std::cout << "enter sub that u want: ";
    std::cin >> sub;*/ // subset 
    int sum[sub], tek[sub], thing[n];
    for (int i = 0;i <= n - 1;i++)
        std::cin >> thing[i];
    allinone(thing, n, 0, sub, tek, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i'm aware of the p and q are duplicate in this my code but it's i need the p for another part of this that i'm not writing that in it ... i actually dont get the down votings ..

Comment: i really not getting ur first line

Comment: @Parano, global variables are, in general, problematic. It will be helpful to you if you can figure out how to avoid using them.

Comment: @Parano, are you talking about the commented out line `// int p = 0, q = 0, i;`?

Comment: i mean this ... int q=p ;

Comment: That my was my attempt at getting the recursion do more than what it did from your posted code. You'll need to take a closer look at it to figure out the right value to initialize `q` to.

Comment: u mean of 2 3 3 is if we set the sequence to {1,2,3,4,5} ?? i compile that with visual studio 2015 and its just alternating the last character ... for example 1,2,3[with arragment get 4 5 3 3 4 5 3 4 ] for the last character